# ¿Cómo calcular la media aritmética del triangulo superior de una matriz?

Tags: c

Muy buenas, me gustaría saber qué estoy haciendo mal en mi  código a la hora de calcular la media aritmética de el triángulo superior de mi matriz 4x4.

Tengo hecho esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DIM 4

void llegir_matriu_de_teclat (float matriu [DIM][DIM]);
void imprimir_matriu (float matriu [DIM][DIM]);
int mitjana_aritmetica_triangle_superior (float matriu [DIM][DIM]);

    void main () {

        float matriu [DIM][DIM];
        int res;

        printf ("\nIntrodueix la matriu: ");
        llegir_matriu_de_teclat (matriu);

        printf ("\nAquesta és la matriu que acabes d'introduïr: \n");
        imprimir_matriu (matriu);

        res = mitjana_aritmetica_triangle_superior (matriu);
        printf ("Resultat de la mitjana aritmètica del triangle superior: %d\n", res);
    }

    // Funció 1.

    void llegir_matriu_de_teclat (float matriu [DIM][DIM]) {

        int i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < DIM; i ++) {
            for (j = 0; j < DIM; j ++) {
                scanf ("%f", &matriu [i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    // Funció 2.

    void imprimir_matriu (float matriu [DIM][DIM]) {

        int i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < DIM; i ++) {
            for (j = 0; j < DIM; j ++) {
                printf ("%6.0f", matriu [i][j]);
            }
            printf ("\n");
        }
    }

    // Funció 3.

    int mitjana_aritmetica_triangle_superior (float matriu [DIM][DIM]) {

        int i, j, sum, res;

        sum = 0;
        res = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < DIM - 1; i ++) {
            for (j = i + 1; j < DIM; j ++) {
                sum = sum + matriu [i][j];
                res = sum / DIM;
            }
        }

        return (res);
    }
```

El compilador no me da error, pero a la hora de calcular la media me da un número incorrecto (lo he comprobado con la calculadora y es un resultado erróneo).

El ejercicio está en Catalán, pero básicamente lo que hago es:

- Función 1: Leer la matriz de teclado.
- Función 2: Imprimir la matriz por pantalla.
- Función 3: Calcular media aritmética del triangulo superior.

Si necesitáis cualquier aclaración, estaré por aquí.

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Un saludo.

Código editado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DIM 4

void llegir_matriu_de_teclat (float matriu [DIM][DIM]);
void imprimir_matriu (float matriu [DIM][DIM]);
int mitjana_aritmetica_triangle_superior (float matriu [DIM][DIM]);

    void main () {

        float matriu [DIM][DIM];
        int res;

        printf ("\nIntrodueix la matriu: ");
        llegir_matriu_de_teclat (matriu);

        printf ("\nAquesta és la matriu que acabes d'introduïr: \n");
        imprimir_matriu (matriu);

        res = mitjana_aritmetica_triangle_superior (matriu);
        printf ("Aquesta és la mitjana aritmètica del triangle superior de la matriu: %d\n", res);
    }

    // Funció 1.

    void llegir_matriu_de_teclat (float matriu [DIM][DIM]) {

        int i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < DIM; i ++) {
            for (j = 0; j < DIM; j ++) {
                scanf ("%f", &matriu [i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    // Funció 2.

    void imprimir_matriu (float matriu [DIM][DIM]) {

        int i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < DIM; i ++) {
            for (j = 0; j < DIM; j ++) {
                printf ("%6.0f", matriu [i][j]);
            }
            printf ("\n");
        }
    }

    // Funció 3.

    int mitjana_aritmetica_triangle_superior (float matriu [DIM][DIM]) {

        int i, j, sum, res, cont;

        cont = 0;   
        sum = 0;
        res = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < DIM - 1; i ++) {
            for (j = i + 1; j < DIM; j ++) {
                sum = sum + matriu [i][j];
                cont ++;
            }
        }

        res = (float) sum / cont;       
        return (res);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La media aritmética es la suma de los elementos dividido la cantidad de elementos sumados, en este caso, sería la suma de los elementos de la triangular superior de la matriz dividido la **cantidad de elementos de la triangular superior**.

En tu código estás dividiendo cada vez que sumás un elemento de la triangular superior, y debes dividir la suma total. Por ejemplo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DIM 4
float mitjana_aritmetica_triangle_superior (float matriu [DIM][DIM]) {

        int i, j, sum;
        float res;
        int cantidadDeElementos;
        sum = 0;



        for (i = 0; i < DIM - 1; i ++) {
            for (j = i + 1; j < DIM; j ++) {
                sum = sum + matriu [i][j];
                cantidadDeElementos++;

            }
        }
        res = (float) sum / cantidadDeElementos;
        return (res);
    } 

void main () {

        float matriu[DIM][DIM] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}};
        float resultado = mitjana_aritmetica_triangle_superior(matriu);
        printf("Resultado: %f", resultado);
    }
```

La variable **cantidadDeElementos** va guardando cuantos elementos tienes en la triangular superior, para finalmente poder dividir la suma total por ésta cantidad.

Comment: Cierto, no sé por qué puse "DIM". ¿Sería correcto usar la variable `i` en lugar de un contador a parte?

En cuanto a tu código no me funciona, me sigue saliendo un resultado erróneo.

Edito mi publicación para que veas el cambio que hice.

Saludos.

Comment: La variable res debe ser de tipo float.

Comment: Tampoco. Ahora el resultado da `0`. Los nombres que estaba introduciendo eran números enteros, la variable `res` no es la que está dando el problema. No entiendo nada, juraría que está todo correcto ...

    Un saludo

Comment: Edite mi respuesta. También debes definir la función de tipo float, ya que el valor a retornar es de ese tipo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, estaba ahí el problema.
Pero no entiendo, si lo que devuelvo es un número entero, ¿por qué tengo que definir la función de tipo `float` y no de tipo `int`?

¡Saludos!

Comment: Lo que devolves es el resultado de una división, por eso debes definir el tipo como float, ya que el resultado no siempre será un entero. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No se si sea problema del compilador, pero me funciona bien sólo cuando incicializo:

**int cantidadDeElementos= 0;**

Comment: ¿Te calcula la media aritmética del triángulo superior?

Comment: La parte entera del resultado y **sin tomar la diagonal** de la matriz. @AlexIglesias